# Limit access to a windows box on one port?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, port, sockets

On my windows box I only need one port open, so I can open a socket connection to an AIR app and retrieve some status data occasionally. This is the only outside connection need.

How can I do this on windows 7, and secure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the Advanced Firewall settings in Windows Firewall, highlight all active inbound rules and hit **Disable Rule** on the right pane. Now right-click on inbound rules and select **New Rule**. Follow the prompts to create a rule for your Adobe AIR app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great thanks for your help! screen shots really appreciated!

Comment: @davivid you are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just configure the firewall to block all connections apart from the port you specify?

Go into Windows firewall -> Advanced and from there you can create new inbound and outbound rules blocking ports. Simply block all apart from the one you require.

Comment: Yeah I guess so, just hadn't done this sort of thing before. Thanks!